# Tuning Tesseract-OCR against specific, preprocessed, single-character samples

Tags: python-3.x, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm having trouble getting characters to be recognized.
I've done a lot of preprocessing in an effort to improve it.
I have the following samples, of which 0, 1, 5 and 8 are not recognized as such (images below).

I am using the following call to tesseract:
`no = pytesseract.image_to_string(img, config=r'--oem 3 --psm 6 tessedit_char_whitelist=0123456789')`

What can I do to improve the accuracy? Is it preprocess, the call to tesseract, or do I need to consider training the model for this particular font?

Thanks

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It seems like it's an issue with the preprocess still, although I'm not clear exactly how, but shrinking the images down to smaller sizes increases accuracy of the OCR.